# How to Convert a Table into a Vector?

Tags: datatable, dolphindb, data-transform

There is a table defined as follows.

[image]

I want to convert this table into a vector. Each column of the table is an element of the vector, and each element is a tuple or vector. Any easy way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the t.values() to convert the table into a vector. The result is as follows.

```
offset  0                                   1
0   string[3](['XOM', 'GS', 'AAPL'])    double[3]([102.1, 33.4, 73.6])
```

Same as the original data type of each column, the elements in the converted vector are STRING vector and DOUBLE vector.